# How to make clang-format add space after asterisk when formatting block comments

Tags: c, clang-format

We have `clang-format` set up to break up block comments in C-code when they exceed the maximum line length. For example,

```
/* This comment is longer than the allowed
 * line length.
 */
```

becomes

```
/* This comment is longer than the
 *allowed line length.
 */
```

How can I make `clang-format` add a space before "allowed"? There is `SpacesInLineCommentPrefix`, but that is explicitly only for line comments `//`, not block comments.

Comment: Actually, for me it works out of the box with any style. In the manual I can not see that `SpacesInLineCommentPrefix` is for one-liner comments only. What are your `Minimum` an `Maximum` settings?

Comment: Which version of `clang-format` is this?